# Why are my pdf's being renamed?

Tags: php, pdf, upload

I have a site that clients can upload pdf's with product information.. For some reason, the pdf's are getting renamed to the 'Office' which will not work as there are many pdf's being uploaded. How do I keep the name of the pdf being uploaded? Any advice would be appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
    session_start();
include('../config.php');
error_reporting(0);

// SESSION CHECK SET OR NOT
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin']))
{
    header('location:index.php');
}


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{


    //When no image is selected
    if($_FILES['image']['name']=='')
    {
        $query      = "INSERT INTO `products` SET Office  = ?,Description = ?,Unit  = ?,Generic  = ?,Category=?";
        $parameters = array($_POST['Office'],$_POST['Description'],$_POST['Unit'],$_POST['Generic'],$_POST['Category']);

    }else{

        $allowed_filetypes = array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif','pjpeg');
        $ext = end((explode(".", $_FILES['image']['name'])));
        $imageName  = $_POST['Office'].'.'.$ext;
        $path = "../".$path.$imageName;
        $tmp =  $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];



        if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
        {

            $error  = 'danger';
            $errormsg = "You uploaded wrong image format";

        }else
        {
                $moved = move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path);

                //Resize the uploaded avatar
                resize($path , '150', '150', $ext);
                $query      = "INSERT INTO `products` SET Office  = ?,Description = ?,Unit  = ?,Generic  = ?,image=?,Category=?";
                $parameters = array($_POST['Office'],$_POST['Description'],$_POST['Unit'],$_POST['Generic'],$imageName,$_POST['Category']);

        }

    }





            //    PDF UPLOAD
            $allowed_filetypes_pdf = array('pdf');
            $ext_pdf = end((explode(".", $_FILES['pdf']['name'])));
            $pdfName  = $_POST['Office'].'.'.$ext_pdf;


             $path = "../".$path_pdf.$_POST['Office']."/";
            //$path_pdf = "../".$path_pdf.$pdfName;
            $pdf=$path_pdf.$pdfName;


            $tmp_pdf =  $_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'];

            if(!in_array($ext_pdf,$allowed_filetypes_pdf))
            {

                $error      = 'danger';
                $errormsg   = "You uploaded wrong image format";


            }else
            {
                $moved1 = move_uploaded_file($tmp_pdf, $path_pdf);

                $query      = "INSERT INTO `products` SET Office  = ?,Description = ?,Unit  = ?,Generic  = ?,image=?,PDF_Path=?,Category=?";
                $parameters = array($_POST['Office'],$_POST['Description'],$_POST['Unit'],$_POST['Generic'],$imageName,$pdf,$_POST['Category']);

            }

        $statement  = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute($parameters);

        $error  = 'success';
        $errormsg = "New User added successfully";

}

 $query = "select DISTINCT(Office) from userinfo ";
 $statement = $db->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();


?>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>

    <title>Add Product</title>
    <?php include "include/head.php" ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/plugins/fileupload/bootstrap-fileupload.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/custom.css" type="text/css" /> 


</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <?php include 'include/header.php'; ?>
    <?php include 'include/topMenu.php'; ?>
    <?php include 'include/sidebar.php'; ?>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="content-header">
            <h1>Add New Product</h1>
        </div> <!-- #content-header -->
        <div id="content-container">
            <?php
            if($errormsg){
                echo "<div class='alert alert-$error'  style='padding-left: 5px;'>$errormsg</div>";
            }?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="portlet">
                        <div class="portlet-header">
                            <h3><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
                                Add Product
                            </h3>
                        </div> <!-- /.portlet-header -->
                        <div class="portlet-content">
                            <div id="error"></div>
                            <form id="validate-basic" action="" data-validate="parsley" method="post" class="form parsley-form ajax_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name">Office</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="Office">
                                        <?php
                                        while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                                        {
                                            echo  "<option value='{$row['Office']}'>{$row['Office']}</option>";
                                        }?>
                                    </select>

                                </div>

                                <div class="input-group">
                                        <h5 style="font-weight: 700; font-size: 13px;">Please select PDF</h5>
                                    <div class="input-group-btn">

                                            <input type="file" name="pdf"/>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group" id="images">
                                    <label for="avatar">Product Image</label>
                                    <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                                        <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 180px; height: 150px;"><img src="../images/avatar/noimage.gif" alt="Product Avatar" /></div>
                                        <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 150px; max-height: 200px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
                                        <div>
                                          <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>

                                          <input type="file" name='image' /></span>
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name">Description</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="Description" name="Description" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row_user['Description'] ?>">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name">Unit</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="Unit" name="Unit" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_POST['Unit'] ?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="select-input">Category</label>
                                    <select id="select-input" name="Category" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="G">Generic</option>
                                        <option value="S">Stationary</option>
                                        <option value="E">Envelopes</option>
                                        <option value="M">Megazine Reprint</option>
                                        <option value="T">Tabs</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="select-input">Generic</label>
                                    <select id="select-input" name="Generic" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                        <option value="0">No</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit"  name="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <!--END PORTLET-CONTENT -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- END PORTLET -->
                </div>
                <!-- END COL -->
            </div>
            <!--END ROW -->
        </div>
        <!-- END CONTENT-CONATINER -->
    </div>
    <!--END CONTENT -->
</div>
<!--END WRAPPER -->
```

'

```
//    EDIT PRODUCT 
    $allowed_filetypes_pdf = array('pdf');
    $ext_pdf = end((explode(".", $_FILES['pdf']['name'])));
    $pdfName  = $_POST['Office'].'.'.$ext_pdf;


    $pdf = ($_FILES['pdf']['name'])?$path_pdf.$pdfName:$_SESSION['oldpdf'];
   // $path = "../".$path_pdf.$_POST['Office']."/";

    $path_pdf = "../".$path_pdf.$pdfName;
    //            chmod($path_pdf, 0777);

        $tmp_pdf =  $_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'];


        $moved1 = move_uploaded_file($tmp_pdf, $path_pdf);

        $query      = "UPDATE  `products` SET Office  = ?,Description = ?,Unit  = ?,Generic  = ?,image=?,PDF_Path=?,Category=? WHERE ID=?";
        $parameters = array($_POST['Office'],$_POST['Description'],$_POST['Unit'],$_POST['Generic'],$imageName,$pdf,$_POST['Category'],$_POST['ID']);
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML?

Comment: Well: `$pdfName  = $_POST['Office'].'.'.$ext_pdf;`... Could it be that `$ext_pdf` is empty?

Comment: @arkascha Yeah.. How do I change it to keep original name?

Comment: Sorry, can't tell you without knowing what data is present. Since you did not share hte html markup as asked by @JayBlanchard, there is little we can say. but I suggest you start looking for the problem yourself: _Why_ is that empty? Where does it get filled from? Why doesn't that work...

Comment: how do I update question? I will add the complete page.

Comment: By using the `edit` button below the question... But please upload only the relevant parts here...

Comment: I have added all the code on page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try
....

```
       //    PDF UPLOAD
    $allowed_filetypes_pdf = array('pdf');
    $ext_pdf = end((explode(".", $_FILES['pdf']['name'])));
    $pdfName  = basename( $_FILES["pdf"]["name"]);


     $path = "../".$path_pdf.$_POST['Office']."/";
    //$path_pdf = "../".$path_pdf.$pdfName;
    $pdf=$path_pdf.$pdfName;


    $tmp_pdf =  $_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'];

    if(!in_array($ext_pdf,$allowed_filetypes_pdf))
    {

        $error      = 'danger';
        $errormsg   = "You uploaded wrong image format";


    }else
    {
        $moved1 = move_uploaded_file($tmp_pdf, $path_pdf);

        $query      = "INSERT INTO `products` SET Office  = ?,Description = ?,Unit  = ?,Generic  = ?,image=?,PDF_Path=?,Category=?";
        $parameters = array($_POST['Office'],$_POST['Description'],$_POST['Unit'],$_POST['Generic'],$imageName,$pdf,$_POST['Category']);

    }
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try" this @AdamSmith? Provide a clear explanation of what you did and why you did it so the OP and future visitors to this question will know what you have done and what should be done.

Comment: It is "name" problem. And your name is coming from: $pdfName . So, it should be your file name.

Comment: @Adam Smith - does not work.. Still changes pdf to office name.

Comment: Edit your post to reflect  the "why" and the "what" @AdamSmith

Comment: that actually worked.. but is adding .pdf extension twice

pdf/msalh.pdf.pdf

Comment: @AdamSmith I tried this.. Though it is returning the file path correctly, it is not saving the pdf ( $path_pdf='pdf/lockton/'; )

Comment: @AdamSmith Ok.. Now that saves pdf path to database but doesnt upload the pdf.

Comment: edit this line: 
        $moved1 = move_uploaded_file($tmp_pdf, $path_pdf); to 
        $moved1 = move_uploaded_file($tmp_pdf, $pdf);

Comment: @AdamSmith Ah.. now edit product and replace pdf doesnt work. I added the code above "Edit Product"

Comment: @AdamSmith It worked one time.. then didn't work again

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

**I made 2 vulnerability fixes for you**

File name extension check is not enough. If you rename .pdf to .php then its passed, and uploaded as well as .pdf. If you check mime type of file, it wont happen again.

In pdf name, you send Office variable, what again vulnerable if the attacker jumps back in folders, and upload it somewhere else. For example if Office's value is ../../Someoffice

```
//$allowed_filetypes_pdf = array('pdf');
//$ext_pdf = end((explode(".", $_FILES['pdf']['name'])));
//$pdfName  = $_POST['Office'].'.'.$ext_pdf;

$name = $_FILES["pdf"]["name"];
$pdfName = substr($name, strrpos($name, "/"));

$dirName = str_replace(["../", "\0"], "", $_POST["Office"]);

$pdfName = $dirName."-".$pdfName; 

//$path = "../".$path_pdf.$_POST['Office']."/";
//$path_pdf = "../".$path_pdf.$pdfName;
//$pdf=$path_pdf.$pdfName;

$path_pdf = "../{$dirName}/{$name}";

$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$type = $finfo->file($tmp_pdf);

if( $type != "application/pdf" )
{
    $error      = 'danger';
    $errormsg   = "You uploaded wrong image format";
}
else
{
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_pdf, $path_pdf);

    $query      = "INSERT INTO `products` SET Office  = ?,Description = ?,Unit  = ?,Generic  = ?,image=?,PDF_Path=?,Category=?";
    $parameters = array($_POST['Office'],$_POST['Description'],$_POST['Unit'],$_POST['Generic'],$imageName,$path_pdf,$_POST['Category']);
}
```

Comment: tried this and it is not uploading.. Once viewing product, there is no pdf.

Comment: No errors at all... Actually, your solution uploads the pdf.. but does not display the file path for admin and the link on client product page does not link to pdf.

Comment: Had you rewrite the `path_pdf`variable for yours?

Comment: Actually, your solution uploads the pdf.. but does not display the file path for admin and the link on client product page does not link to pdf

Comment: it is uploading pdf but not saving the pdf path in database. therefore it is not linked for clients nor displayed in admin

My original code above was saving correctly, the only issue was.. It was renaming the pdfs, which I did not want to happen

Comment: path would be "pdf/file name"